# PHP - sprintf with multiple url values

Tags: php, url, printf

I am using `sprintf()` **PHP** function and trying to format this *url* like:

```
"/api/v1/post/1/225883"
```

I have:

```
const API_URL = '/api/v1';
const POST_ENDPOINT = '/post';
$this->client->getId()
$this->post->getDestinationId()
```

I tried:

```
sprintf(self::API_URL . self::POST_ENDPOINT,
        $this->client->getId(),
        $this->post->getDestinationId());
```

And I get: `/api/v1/post`

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the format string:

```
$url = sprintf("%s%s/%s/%s", self::API_URL, self::POST_ENDPOINT,
    $this->client->getId(),
    $this->post->getDestinationId());
```

Comment: although  I would suggest to replace two last `%s` with `%d` to narrow the type of data those IDS are

Comment: @JanMyszkier Maybe, but that wouldn't work if they have significant leading zeroes.